# Sql : Generate Matrix from two tables have many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: droit, role and role_droit. I have many to many relation between droit and role, and role_droit as association table.Please find below the diagram.I would return a matrix like this the diagram below named : **Result 2**  If we have an intersection between 2 tables  **droit** and **role** we make **1** else **0**. I tried with this query but I got the result in the diagram **result 1** :

```
SELECT matrix_view.droit_id,
    case when matrix_view.aid = 1 then haspair end as  "role A" ,
    case when matrix_view.aid = 2 then haspair end as  "role B" ,
    case when matrix_view.aid = 3 then haspair end as  "role C" ,
    case when matrix_view.aid = 4 then haspair end as  "role D"

        from (SELECT allRD.aid as aid, allRD.droit_id, max(case when RD.role_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HasPair
        from (select distinct a.role_id as aid, b.droit_id as droit_id
        from role a cross join droit b ) as allRD left outer join role_Droit RD
        on allRD.aid = RD.role_id and allRD.droit_id = RD.droit_id
        group by  allRD.droit_id,  allRD.aid
        order by  allRD.aid) AS matrix_view
```

I have used Postgres as SGBD. Please help me to have the **result 2** !!! 
Please check the attached image to show tables ans results 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFKro.png)

Comment: Sorry,  please help me to have the result 2 !!! Please see the attached image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query.
I only extended your query by `group by` the columns. And merge them with `sum`.

```
select A.droit_id, sum(A."role A") as "role A", sum(A."role B") as "role B", sum(A."role C") as "role C", sum(A."role D") as "role D"
from (
    SELECT matrix_view.droit_id,
        case when matrix_view.aid = 1 then haspair end as  "role A" ,
        case when matrix_view.aid = 2 then haspair end as  "role B" ,
        case when matrix_view.aid = 3 then haspair end as  "role C" ,
        case when matrix_view.aid = 4 then haspair end as  "role D"

    from (
        SELECT allRD.aid as aid, allRD.droit_id, max(case when RD.role_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HasPair
            from (select distinct a.role_id as aid, b.droit_id as droit_id
            from role a cross join droit b ) as allRD left outer join role_Droit RD
            on allRD.aid = RD.role_id and allRD.droit_id = RD.droit_id
            group by  allRD.droit_id,  allRD.aid
            order by  allRD.aid
    ) AS matrix_view
) A
group by A.droit_id
order by A.droit_id
```

Or this:

```
SELECT matrix_view.droit_id,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 1 then haspair end) as  "role A" ,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 2 then haspair end) as  "role B" ,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 3 then haspair end) as  "role C" ,
    sum(case when matrix_view.aid = 4 then haspair end) as  "role D"

from (
        SELECT allRD.aid as aid, allRD.droit_id, max(case when RD.role_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HasPair
        from (
                select distinct a.role_id as aid, b.droit_id as droit_id
                from role a cross join droit b 
             ) as allRD 
        left outer join role_Droit RD
        on allRD.aid = RD.role_id and allRD.droit_id = RD.droit_id
        group by  allRD.droit_id,  allRD.aid
        order by  allRD.aid
    ) AS matrix_view
group by matrix_view.droit_id
order by matrix_view.droit_id
```

Comment: Now haw can I return for example the id_role, id_droit and the haspair in intersection ! I have tried concat ! like this : 1,1,2  or 1,1,1

Comment: very good, but it seems to be a new question and need a new post to answer it. Please ask a new question.